# wordpress acts like functions.php doesn't exist

Tags: functions

I was developing my theme on my localhost windows server, everything was ok, until I decided to transfer it to my hosting. I transfered it as all wordpress sites I have transfered before,changed live site and wordpress url,but just when I activate my theme, none of functions located in functions.php file are used, for every single fuction used from there  I get 
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function`
where could be the problem? Everything with the transfer is ok, cause site works like it should with twenty ten theme, also inside pages works too, because I dont use any functions from there, but in frontpage where is tim thumb used and several custom functions, it fails to use any of them, no mater what it does, it just seems functions.php file doesnt exist. Any ideas?
Error log: http://pastebin.com/hdbYUjxT

Heres whole functions.php file: 
http://pastebin.com/ZXFX2wV5

Comment: "*This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.*"

Comment: I don't know, tried to give all the information I have, is this because I end question with "Any ideas?". Tried to be specific as possible, I would be grateful if you could tell me what info is missing and could be improved, for this and future questions :)

Comment: Well, for one, you need to list the **actual error messages** you're observing. Where applicable, you need to list the **actual code** that is causing the issue/not behaving as expected. And in general, it is helpful to indicate: **1)** What you're trying to accomplish, **2)** What you *did*, **3)** What you *expected* to happen, and **4)** What *didn't* happen/what happened *unexpectedly*.

Comment: You have probably a syntax error in your `functions.php`, a missing closing quote or something similar.

Comment: can you share the functions you should be activating meaning this one "news_size()"

Comment: I've added whole functions.php file in OP, point is, it works localy, but fails to work in web server.

Comment: Can you please include your theme's `index.php`?  That's where the error is generated, so that's where we start debugging.  I notice that there's no function called `news_size()` in your functions.php - where is this function located?

Comment: @EimantasKasperiūnas Any progress? If note, I'm flagging this Q for deletion.

Answer (score 2):

When developing locally, **always** set the following in your wp-config.php to **see all errors**:

```
// DEBUG
error_reporting( E_ALL );

/** Php error log */
@ini_set( 'log_errors',         'On');
@ini_set( 'display_errors',     'On');

define( 'WP_DEBUG',             true );
define( 'SAVEQUERIES',          true );
// file: /core_root/content/debug.log
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG',         true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY',     true );
```

Comment: I understand where you're going here, but as it is, this doesn't really constitute an **answer**. Not flagging as such, though, because the underlying problem is that the question **isn't a real question**.

Comment: I hoped that the OP will update his Q with more insights, when showing the complete set of errors. Currently he's not knowing how to get error output, so let's just see where the Q is going.

Comment: thanks for advice, but in localhost, I do not get any errors but in web server same error appears as beffore: 
http://pastebin.com/hdbYUjxT
even if I delete that function call in index, after that if fails on second function and so on as long as theres any functions from functions.php